# Can't see newest questions directly

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

Whenever I load a site I have to click (tap?) on the question button before I can see featured and newest questions. It is just mildly irritating.

Here's a GIF image:

[image]

Is this intentional or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking on "Questions" takes you to the questions page, which is at:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions

That is a different page from the homepage:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Both pages show a list of questions, but the sort options on both are different. The homepage only shows you questions based on activity or "hotness", whereas the questions pages have a number of sort options. The homepage also *isn't* paginated so only shows a limited number of questions.

This is more obvious on the full site where question pages (*all* questions pages other than the homepage; including search results, tag pages etc.) have a different layout than the homepage (they show an excerpt of the question text as well as its title).